# How to isolate styles using spacing

Tags: microsoft-word, formatting, text-formatting

In Microsoft Word, it is possible to add some space before and after text, using spacing (menu Format, Paragraph, Spacing).

I'd like to separate a piece of text, belonging to a certain style, I had thought of conditional spacing:

- If the following style is equal than the current one, then spacing=0.
- If the following style is different than the current one, then spacing=8 (e.g.).

Does anybody know if this is possible and if not, what can I do to force some kind of isolation of text, belonging to a certain style?

To explain more clearly, hereby a small screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about conditional formating, but can you not use styles? If you create a new style (based on "No Spacing" for example) then right click the style > Modify > Format > Paragraph > Spacing, you can set an "After" value. If you also check the "Don't add space between paragraphs of the same style" then the source code won't be messed up by additional spaces.

[image]

Comment: That's the solution indeed: I add some line spacing before, some line spacing after, and I check the checkbox "Don't add space between paragraphs of the same style" (I had already created a specific style for this).